# MySql内で条件分岐処理の設定をしたいです。

Tags: mysql

お世話になっております。

どうか、アドバイス等を頂ければと存じます。よろしくお願い致します。

MySql内でテーブルをクリックすると、各タブが並んでいて、一番左側の”表示”タブをクリックするとそのテーブル内のフィールドが横の列に並びます。

今回の例ですと、ウェブサイトのURLを定義したテーブルで各フィールドに、例えば、page_id、name、url、filename、・・・とあります。

filenameとはそのサイトのテンプレートファイルなのですが、これをそのサイトのURLにフラッグを立てて、複数のテンプレートファイルに差し替えたいのですが、mysql側でその処理を設定することは可能でしょうか。（事情がありphp側でその処理を設定することができないため。）(仮にphp側で設定すると以下の様な設定になります。)

```
if($_GET['id'] == 1 )  {
$this->tpl_mainpage = 'file1.tpl';
} else if($_GET['id'] == 2 )  {
$this->tpl_mainpage = 'file2.tpl';
} else {
$this->tpl_mainpage = 'file3.tpl';
}
```

Comment: 「MySql内でテーブルをクリック」ということは何かのGUIを使っているのだと思いますが、そのGUIツールの名前を書いたほうがいいと思います。

Comment: tmtms様、ありがとうございます。　phpMyAdmin - 2.8.2.4、MySQL - 5.0.95です。

Answer (score 0):

SQLでよければ
※以下を実行すると、全レコードのfilenameを書き換えてしまいますのでご注意ください。
（追記）「サイトのURLにフラッグを立てて」とあったので、全レコードのfilenameを書き換えないよう、条件を追加しました。
テーブル名のところと、WHERE文のidの箇所を書き換えてください。

```
UPDATE テーブル名 SET
  filename = CASE page_id
    WHEN 1 THEN 'file1.tpl'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'file2.tpl'
    ELSE 'file3.tpl'
END
WHERE page_id IN (1, 2, その他対象となるid)
```

Comment: pontaway様、説明不足にもかかわらず、ご教授頂きまして感謝いたします。流れを補足いたしますと、サイトのトップページから詳細ページを開く際の詳細ページのテンプレートファイルを差し替えたいため、トップページで詳細ページ用のリンクにhttp://www.xxx.com&id=1の様なフラッグを立てる想定です。このidは前述のテーブルとは別のテーブル（サイトの商品情報を格納）に存在しているものです。前述のpage_idは説明したテーブル（サイトのURL情報を格納）内の個々のデータに割り振られている主キーの様なもので、このidとは別のものです。以上を踏まえた上で、頂きました記述でも宜しいでしょうか。

Comment: 必要なのはテーブルの更新ではなく、差し替えるテンプレートファイルの文字列が取得できればよいということでしょうか？詳細ページ用リンクとして付けられたidから、該当テーブルのpage_idもしくはfilenameを特定する方法が必要です。

Comment: テンプレートを替える、使うtplファイル自体を条件によって違うものにするということです。URLにフラッグを立てずにすむの‌​であれば、それにこしたことがないです（‌​当初はphpで実装だったのでURLフラッ‌​グを考えておりました。）。現在二つのテー‌​ブルが関与しています。Dtb_produ‌​cts(商品テーブル)とdtb_page‌​layout(URLテーブル)の二つです‌​。要は、dtb_productsのidと‌​いうフィールドが1であれば、dtb_pa‌​gelayoutのpage_idが1、f‌​ilenameがproducts/det‌​ail、あるいはdtb_products‌​のidが2であればdtb_pagelay‌​outのpage_idが1、filena‌​meがproducts/detail2、‌​というようにテンプレートだけ差し替える設‌​定をmysqlで行いたいです。(page‌​_idはここでは同じURLなので同一、f‌​ilenameはproudctsディレク‌​トリー内の違うtplファイルになります。‌​) 以上の条件でどのようなSQLになるかご教授いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 以下を明確にしてください。【１．dtb_pagelayoutの構造】dtb_productsのidから、dtb_pagelayoutのレコードが特定できますか？dtb_pagelayoutのPKは何ですか？コメントいただいた内容だと、dtb_pagelayoutにはpage_id=1でfilenameの異なる複数のレコードが存在することになります。【２．INPUTとして使用できる項目】dtb_productsのidがリクエストに来る前提でよいですか？URLフラッグを使わない場合は、何によってテンプレートを区別するのですか？【３．OUTPUTに使用する内容】dtb_pagelayoutのfilenameをtplファイル名として使うのでしょうか？productsディレクトリ内の検索が必要であれば、そのPHP処理が必要になるかと思われます。